# How to display full server date and time in VB.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to display full server date and time in vb.net ?

i want to display server date as `20-Nov-2010` in textbox1 and time as `08:11:00 AM` in Textbox2 on page load event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display server time:

Markup:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1" />
<br />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox2" />
```

Code-behind:

```
Imports System.Globalization

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' pay attention to DateTime.Today '
    TextBox1.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")

    ' culture-specific: '
    Dim ci As CultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US")
    TextBox2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("T", ci)

    ' or culture-independent: '
    TextBox2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt")
End Sub
```

---

If you want to display client time:

Markup:

```
<!-- Adding the reference to jQuery CDN, for example, by Google -->
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Formatting function -->
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var names = ["Jan", "Feb", "March", "Apr", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sepr", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
        var now = new Date();
        $('#TextBox1').val(now.getDate() + '-' + names[now.getMonth()] + '-' + now.getFullYear());
        var minutes = now.getMinutes();
        $('#TextBox2').val(now.getHours() + ':' + formatLeadingZero(minutes) + ':' + formatLeadingZero(now.getSeconds()) + ' ' + formatTimePeriod(minutes));
    });

    function formatLeadingZero(value) {
        return (value < 10) ? '0' + value : value;
    }

    function formatTimePeriod(value) {
        return (value < 12) ? "AM" : "PM";
    }
</script>

<!-- ASP.NET controls -->
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox1" />
<br />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBox2" />
```

Comment: I want date in Textbox1 as 20-Nov-2010 (THis format )

and time in in textbox2 as 08:10:00 AM (This format )

Comment: @user512392: I added both server and client time

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
Response.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString())
```

Update: (following updated question)

```
Dim now As DateTime = DateTime.Now
textbox1.Text = now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
textbox2.Text = now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt")
```

You may want to read up on [custom DateTime format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Comment: I think this is client Time format .. !!

i want to display server date as 20-Nov-2010 in tetbox1 and time as 08:11:00 AM in Textbox2 on page load event

Comment: @user512392 - This is _server side_ code. It will get the latest time _on the server_ (`DateTime.Now`), get the string representation (`ToString()`) and output it (`Response.Write`).

Comment: @user512392 - also, if you have such specific needs, next time _add them to the question_. We don't read minds here.

Comment: @user No,it is not client time as the code is not run on the client.code is run on the server,so it server time format.

Answer (score 1):

```
textbox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
textbox2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt")
```

Comment: Can u plz tell me.... if i host my site .... then this controls ...textbox1 and textbox2 will display the time and date of server or client ?

Comment: @user512392; those will display the server's time, because they execute on the server.  If you want to display the user's time, you need to use Javascript (or any other client-side script).